# Glitches with cross-browser CSS support for 100% transform translate animation movement

Tags: css, animation, transform, translate

I've recently dug out an [old piece of JS code](https://github.com/lvl99/jquery-lvl99-nicescreen/tree/develop) I wrote that I thought I'd put online for free use, and I've found that one CSS animation rendering issue that stumped me 3 years ago is still acting up today.

It involves animating an element from `left:100%`/`transform: translateX(100%)` or `top:100%`/`translateY(100%)` to `0`, which is effectively *from off the right or bottom of the parent element to the origin*.

I've been testing in Google Chrome on Mac OS X (47.0.2526.111) and get glitchy rendering occurring, which is visible in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/lvl99/g29o0005/

The glitch essentially shifts the transitioning element immediately to the origin position, then animates to off the screen to then jump back to the origin position.

Back when I was originally debugging the issue I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388495/css3-transform-animation-doesnt-render-so-well-in-safari-uiwebview) and a working solution was to change the `100%` value to something like `92.5%` in the CSS. This works for `left`/`translateX` values, but not for `top`/`translateY` values.

One interesting aspect about this glitch is that rendering negative values back to origin has no issue, i.e. `left:-100%`/`transform:translateX(-100%)` and `top:-100%`/`transform:translateY(-100%)` all seem to render perfectly (*from off the top or left of the parent element to origin* with no jumping).

I tested with Google Chrome on iPad and latest version of Google Chrome Canary and the rendering issues seem to be resolved. I've also tested with Mozilla Firefox (43.0.4) and Safari (8.0.8 (10600.8.9)) on computer which seem to render it mostly faithfully, however with the 3d and card transition styles there are some layering issues (could this be a `z-index` or `transform-style: preserve-3d` issue?)

I have an old MacBook Pro (Mid-2009) so perhaps it's something to do with my graphics card. I was wondering if anyone else has had any similar rendering issues or experience with off-screen elements animating. I've already utilised `backface-visibility: hidden` to aid any other rendering issues.

Since Google Chrome Canary renders it a lot better, I'm hoping that it will be resolved in the regular build of Google Chrome, but for cross-browser across many older versions it would be beneficial to find out a means to have non-jumpy rendering.

Comment: There is a lot of code and animations in there. Can you simplify it to just a minimal verifiable example?

Comment: Cheers; now updated to reference to plugin files via RawGit CDN instead of embedded within the jsfiddle

Comment: That looks a lot simpler :) By the way, I have tried selecting each of the 4 options and I don't see any issues. I am using Chrome v 43.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. No jumping or strange rendering issues at all? Are you on Mac or Windows? Maybe it is my graphics card.

I notice too that the 3d mode seems to render things OK in Chrome, so maybe there's some 3d rendering exploit I can trigger to ensure the other modes render better.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 @Matt and no, I don't see any rendering issues.

Comment: Good to know it's OK on Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a new Mac computer now and revisiting this issue over a year later I see that Google Chrome seems to play nicely with this now. It may have been my old 7 year old Mac's graphics card which was the issue!